# Window Function in MySql 8.0 wont work - how to rectify "not valid at this position")

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I am trying to use a window function in MySQL Workbench version 8.0.

This is my query:

```
Select user_id,
COUNT(user_id) OVER(Partition By user_id) as total_actions
from user_log
```

Im getting an error under the open parenthesis after Over, saying its not valid at that position.
Im looking at a user log which tracks all actions users do in our app, i'm trying to get a total number of actions for each user - basically how many times each user ID appears in the table.

I would also like to put a time period on it if i can get it to work, there is a date_created column so would i just add in a regular

```
WHERE date_created BETWEEN X and Y
```

or is it different because its a window function?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you run this query: `SELECT VERSION();`? You might have MySQL Workbench 8.0, but that's just a client. What matters is the version of the MySQL Server. If that's version 5.7 or earlier, then the window functions won't work until you upgrade the MySQL Server.

Comment: it runs under mysql 8 normally see https://dbfiddle.uk/T9wRKeAf i am guessing you have an older version running

Comment: Thanks! @BillKarwin i ran that and got 5.7 :( guess i will talk to I.T and ask for an upgrade thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8.0 introduced window functions. Older MySQL versions do not have this and will throw an error. Based on your question it seems that you are using an older MySQL version, because your query should work well in modern MySQL versions. So, if you want to use window functions, you will need to upgrade your MySQL version. Since that may require a large preliminary work, for the time being you can use aggregates, like:

```
select <some columns>
from <some table>
group by <some field>
```

Your query would look like

```
select user_id, count(user_id)
from user_log
group by user_id
where date_created between X and Y
```